# How do i create duplicates (same keys) in React list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, duplicates

I'm actually need to create duplicates with same keys. Something like this:

```
const list = [...items, ...items]
```

and in my render:

```
{list.map(item => (
    <div key={item.id}>
        <Image src={item.image} width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
))
```

I need every duplicate to be absolutely identical so they do not load or process images twice. End result will be:

[image 1] [image 2] [image 1] [image 2]

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can merge two list, I'm still not very clear what are you asking, do write if have any doubt.

```
function Test() {
  const [firstList, setFirstList] = useState([{ a: "2" }, { b: "3" }]);
  const [secondList, setSecondList] = useState([{ c: "4" }, { d: "5" }]);

  useEffect(() => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(firstList));
  });

  function mergeList() {
    secondList.forEach((d) => setFirstList((firstList) => [...firstList, d]));
  }

  return <button onClick={mergeList}>Click</button>;
}
export default Test;
```

Or you can change your function to be like this,(never tried myself) --

```
  function mergeList() {
    let previous = firstList;
    secondList.forEach((d) => previous.push(d));
    setFirstList(previous);
  }
```

Comment: I have a list of images. I need to render them twice in one parent element. For example i have list of two images. If i render them twice with unique keys, i get 4 requests for 2 images. What i need is somehow inform react that image 1 and image 3 is the same

Comment: Ok, edit your question and write the data example (format) in detail, will try to solve that. for now it is const list = [...items, ...items]

Comment: It is in my question. Second line with [...items, ...items]